# I am getting this error while running my scheduled job

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

```
Message Executed as user: NT SERVICE\\SQLSERVERAGENT. Incorrect syntax near '+'. \[SQLSTATE 42000\] (Error 102) Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon. \[SQLSTATE 42000\] (Error 319). NOTE: The step was retried the requested number of times (5) without succeeding. The step failed.
```

i want to create job step for my log file backup. I want to append date and time with the file name. This is code:

```
declare @backupdate Nvarchar(20)
set @backupdate = REPLACE(convert (nvarchar, getdate(), 120), '/','')
\--add job step to job
EXEC sp_add_jobstep
@job_name='LogBackup',
@step_name='Log_file_Backup',
@subsystem='TSQL',
@command = 'BACKUP log AdventureWorks2022 TO DISK ="C:\\SQLBackups\\AdventureWorks\\log\\LogBackup"+@backupdate+".bak" with INIT',
@retry_attempts = 5,
@retry_interval = 5;
go
```

I have tried this code as well:

```
declare @backupdate Nvarchar(20)
set @backupdate = REPLACE(convert (nvarchar, getdate(), 120), '/','')
--add job step to job
EXEC sp_add_jobstep
@job_name='LogBackup',
@step_name='Log_file_Backup',
@subsystem='TSQL',
@command = 'BACKUP log AdventureWorks2022 TO DISK ="C:\\SQLBackups\\AdventureWorks\\log\\LogBackup"+"@backupdate"+".bak" with INIT',
@retry_attempts = 5,
@retry_interval = 5;
go
```

still getting the error

Comment: ="C:\\SQLBackups\\AdventureWorks\\log\\LogBackup"+@backupdate+".bak" is wrong. The syntax doesn't allow expressions in the path, only variables or string literals. Create a variable and put the expression there and then call the backup command. Also, don't use " " , use single quotes for strings

Comment: Just to clarify siggemannen's response:
`DECLARE @backupdate NVARCHAR(20) = REPLACE(convert (nvarchar, getdate(), 120), '/','');
DECLARE @Cmd NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'BACKUP log AdventureWorks2022 TO DISK =''C:\\SQLBackups\\AdventureWorks\\log\\LogBackup'+@backupdate+'.bak'' with INIT'` then use the variable for `@command`.

Comment: However, this is going to create backups which consistently use the `DATETIME` from when you create the job, rather than the `DATETIME` of the backup, which I don't think is your intention.

Comment: `DECLARE @Cmd NVARCHAR(MAX) = ' DECLARE @path NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''C:\\SQLBackups\\AdventureWorks\\log\\LogBackup''+REPLACE(convert (nvarchar, getdate(), 120), ''/'','''')+''.bak''; BACKUP log AdventureWorks2022 TO DISK = @path with INIT'` may get you closer to what you want.

Comment: thanks for the clarification patrick hurst this error has been resolved but now i am getting this error:Executed as user: NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT. Cannot open backup device 'C:\SQLBackups\AdventureWorks\Log\LogBackup2024-02-20 18:12:06.bak'. Operating system error 123(The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.). [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 3201)  BACKUP LOG is terminating abnormally. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 3013).  NOTE: The step was retried the requested number of times (1) without succeeding.  The step failed.

Comment: I don't think `:` is valid in file paths.

Comment: The path refers to the path on the server not the client, and the SQL Server service user needs to have the right permissions on those files/folders.